# Pygame - Is There A Way To Get The String From fontType.render?

Tags: python, text, dialog, pygame

I'm trying to print dialogue in a box letter by letter (like pokemon or most RPGs) and I'm wondering if theres a way to get the string from a fontType.render variable, like so:

```
self.Coffee = self.fontType.render("Ooh! French Vanilla!", 0, (0,0,0,))
```

I tried doing:

```
self.Coffee[0]
```

..but I got:

```
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am trying to ***avoid*** making a variable for the string like this (although it might work, it just seems sloppy or just too messy for how I'm doing the rest of the code):

```
dialogue = "Ooh! French Vanilla!"
self.Coffee = self.fontType.render(dialogue, 0, (0,0,0))
```

I hope I made myself clear enough, if not let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`pygame.Surface` docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) suggest the object is essentially a canvas onto which your text is painted. Once you put text on it, it is an image of text, so there wouldn't be any practical way to retrieve it once painted (not impossible just impractical). I'd go with the approach of storing your dialogue text in a variable as you suggested. I tend to do this anyway when I am posting text as any sort of prompt or message on the screen. I'd rather see this:

```
dialogue = 'Ooh! French Vanilla!'
self.Coffee = self.fontType.render(dialogue, 0, (0,0,0))
```

than this:

```
self.Coffee = self.fontType.render('Some really long dialogue that might make me want this on two lines', 0, (0,0,0))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After some messing around with the code, the way I was trying to avoid wasn't actually that bad.